# Encrypting configuration parameters

Tags: cloudbees

How can I store a configuration property such that its value can't be read anytime with bees config:list? We use a master password as a System property (although we are open to other options there) that allows us to decrypt other passwords. However, we realized that any user with CB SDK access can easily list that value. What are our options here to store it encrypted or other ideas for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no encryption option available yet, unless you were to bake it yourself in a ClickStack, for example.

Still, this would be an interesting feature, and I will talk about this possibility with my colleagues.

Comment: Thanks. The implementation I have in mind doesn't seem difficult, here are my thoughts:
-when a user sets a config parameter, just add a flag to the SDK call to say that it should be hidden (e.g. bees config:set propertyName=propertyValue --hidden)
-then a modification to the response on the bees config:list, when it outputs the parameters set for that application, would simply show a hidden value for that particular property (e.g. propertyName=HIDDEN)

I could be overlooking something here but if not, that seems simple enough.

Comment: It might be tricky, since the stack would have access to it, and someone with vile intent could modify the ClickStack URL and get all parameters in clear.